# Local max and min of $e^{−x} − e^{−4x}$

Tags: calculus

Find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum values of f on the given interval.
$f(x) = e^{−x} − e^{−4x}$,   on $[0, 1]$

The min is obviously 0 but I'm struggling to find the max without using a graphing calculator.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Hint: find the zero of $f'(x)$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I tried that. 0 = -e^(-x) + 4e^(-4x). e^(-x) = 4e^(-4x). How would I proceed from here?

Comment: Divide both sides by $e^{-x} \ne 0$ and see where that takes you.

Comment: I tried that and made a silly mistake. Got it, thanks so much for the help ^-^